# php combining two arrays under a joint key

Tags: php

I have the following two Arrays:

```
$Array1 = array(array('x1','x2','x3'),array('x4','x5','x6'));
$Array2 = array(array('z1','z2','z3'),array('z4','z5','z6'));
```

when printed they return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x1] => x1
            [x2] => x2
            [x3] => x3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x4] => x4
            [x5] => x5
            [x6] => x6
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [z1] => z1
            [z2] => z2
            [z3] => z3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [z4] => z4
            [z5] => z5
            [z6] => z6
        )

)
```

How can I combine them to produce a single array like the example below, where they are combined using the same key:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x1] => x1
            [x2] => x2
            [x3] => x3
            [z1] => z1
            [z2] => z2
            [z3] => z3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x4] => x4
            [x5] => x5
            [x6] => x6
            [z1] => z4
            [z2] => z5
            [z3] => z6
        )

)
```

I have tried using:

```
array_merge=($Array1,$Array2) 

array_merge_recursive($Array1,$Array2) 

array_combine($Array1,$Array2) [which genereated an error, so I guess I was using it wrong]
```

$Array1 + $Array2

but none of these have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that you are using these functions on multidimensional arrays. You were on the right track with array_merge but you have to call that on the second level of you arrays and you will have to iterate the first level

So calling [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) on each second level element in those arrays should work:

```
$Array1 = array(array('x1','x2','x3'),array('x4','x5','x6'));
$Array2 = array(array('z1','z2','z3'),array('z4','z5','z6'));
$output = array();

foreach ($Array1 as $key=>$value) {
    $output[$key] = array_merge($value, $Array2[$key]);
    // same as:
    //$output[$key] = array_merge($Array1[$key], $Array2[$key]);
}
```

And you will have the final value in **$output**

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($Array1 as $key => $arr) {
  $output[] = array_merge($arr, $Array2[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$Array1 = array_merge(array('x1','x2','x3'),array('x4','x5','x6'));
$Array2 = array_merge(array('z1','z2','z3'),array('z4','z5','z6'));

$Array = array_merge($Array1,$Array2)
```

[docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$arr1 = array_merge($Array1[0],$Array2[0]);
$arr2 = array_merge($Array1[1],$Array2[1]);
$array = array($arr1, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works even if you have no numeric indexes:

```
$Array1 = array(array('x1','x2','x3'),array('x4','x5','x6'));
$Array2 = array(array('z1','z2','z3'),array('z4','z5','z6'));

$new_array = array();

foreach($Array1 as $key => $val) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $Array2)) {
        $new_array[$key] = array_merge($val, $Array2[$key]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$Array1 = array(array('x1' => 'x1', 'x2' => 'x2', 'x3' => 'x3'),
    array('x4' =>'x4','x5' =>'x5','x6' =>'x6'));


$Array2 = array(array('z1' =>'z1', 'z2' =>'z2', 'z3' =>'z3'),
array('z4' =>'z4','z5' =>'z5', 'z6' =>'z6'));


$final=array();
foreach($Array1 as $key1=>$arr1)
{
 foreach($Array2 as $key2=>$arr2)
  {
    if($key1==$key2)
    {
        $sub=array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
        $final[]=$sub;
    }
   }  
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

You can chcek the working demo here(http://codepad.org/1Eu9vjah)